# Windows 10 showing duplicate Folders under user

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10-preview

I just set up a new Windows 10 machine.  Under my "user name" folder there are duplicates of a few of the standard Windows folders such as Music, Downloads, and Document.

Any idea why this is happening?  It does not cause problems, just clutter.

[image]

Comment: Have you changed the location of your Documents, Downloads and Music folders? I had this issue with a laptop and it was caused by the fact that I’d changed the location of those folders from the small C: drive to the much larger D: drive and Windows was showing both locations. I ended up chalking it up to a bug in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was caused by [moving my personal folders](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/moving-your-personal-data-folders-in-windows-vista-the-easy-way/) (documents/videos/music/...) to a cloud drive folder (onedrive/dropbox/...).
The windows file explorer will still display those folders in the old location, even if they have moved somewhere else. This feature seems to be called "[know folder redirection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776911(v=vs.85))".

However, some Windows Updates seem to be unaware of redirected known folders and start to re-create the initial folder locations if they are not present anymore. So you will end up with 2 folders. One is a special link to your redirected known folder and one is the empty, re-created folder.

Make sure to create a backup of all your data before deleting the unwanted empty folder. Since both folders have the same name, programs might have trouble keeping them apart.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and this was the fix for my laptop.  Open "My Computer", click "File" at the top left, go to "Change Folder and Search Options", go to the bottom and unselect both privacy options and finally hit "clear".  Windows has a heck of a time keeping track of Quick Access items, including folder access.  Give this a shot, should work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had duplicate Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures and Videos folders in my user folder (in the left navigation screen). I solved this by doing the following:

1. Open a Windows Explorer folder
2. Click on "View" in the folder Menu
3. Select "Options" on the far right of the menu
4. Select "View" in the Folder Options window that opens
5. Scroll down to "Navigation Pane"
6. De-select "Show all folders"

That's it.

P.S. Be sure to ascertain what is in the secondary folders before you de-select "Show all folders" (found several new files, in my case) and make copies before making the de-selection.